How to make complex spa with fable feliz?
I am newbie in web dev, but I need fast dev medium level app.
On start i confused how to compose react components with router and other components with props. Master pager(layouts,menu), theme(dark|light), lang(labels, and values), authorize. with Webapi(C#) as backend.
I tried small test myself and read official docs for Fable.Feliz, but samples from site is very simple.

You're probably best to/froing on questions like this on the F# discord (or perhaps the slack) - this question isn't a good fit for SO

Thank you. I spent few days to  study it and I understood many things from subject. If you want to see results, welcome to https://github.com/altbodhi/FelizApp. it is really fantastic robust with simple and powerful language
